# Thesis topics on p-adic number theory for an undergraduate

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I've been reading and learning about p-adic numbers the past few months for my undergraduate thesis, and they interest me very much. Any suggestions on a thesis topic I could work with the p-adic numbers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A fascinating topic is *Quadratic forms and the Hasse-Minkowski Theorem*. Here we see how to solve certain quadratic equations in several variables over the rational numbers by considering local solutions over all $p$-adic fields, including the real number, for $p=\infty$. Have a look, for example, at [this undergraduate project](https://www.math.toronto.edu/undergrad/projects-undergrad/EnterMAT477in2012march13byJurajMilcakOnHasseMinkowskiThm.pdf). You could generalise it to finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider a topic in algebraic coding:
''Modular and p-adic Cyclic Codes'',
A. Robert Calderbank, N. J. A. Sloane, published 1995 in Designs, Codes, Cryptography
DOI:10.1007/BF01390768

Comment: Will it be possible to create a thesis on this if I never had any background on cyclic codes? If yes, could you recommend any resources/books that I could read. Thank you!